# Progress Dialog Message Text is not visible in Android-M

Tags: android, progressdialog

Message text of progress dialog is not visible. Please see the attached screenshot.
Code:
   `dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", getResources().getString(R.string.scan_devices), true);`

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Put your Message Here...!!!", getResources().getString(R.string.scan_devices), true);

Comment: @SarfarajMakvana this is also not helping.. still the same issue

Comment: you are get any error or permission problem? check your logcat

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Is it resolved? If yes, please help.

Comment: @Kameswari i have fixed this issue by applying the theme on ProgressDialog, 
        myDialog = ProgressDialog.show(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.NewDialog), "",
     "Loading...", true);

In Style define the theme as follows,
<style name="NewDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
  <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>// change color
 </style>

Comment: @Kameswari cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog =  ProgressDialog.show(ExtractCallData.this, "title", "Message",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
progress.setTitle("Loading");
progress.setMessage("Wait while loading...");
progress.show();
// To dismiss the dialog
progress.dismiss();
```

OR

```
ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Wait while loading...");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);      
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.scan_devices));
            progressDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Above what ever you are used was work properly in even Android-M also, **I think problem with Context you are passed use proper context**. Once try bellow one also

```
    public static ProgressDialog progress(Context context, String msg, boolean isCancelable) throws Exception {
    try {
        final ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(msg);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(isCancelable);
        mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(isCancelable);
        mProgressDialog.show();
        mProgressDialog.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        return mProgressDialog;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```